# Grammatical error in following sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, british-english, sentence

I am an IT Professional with over 12 years experience in Website Development, IT Management, IT Support and project management.

I have the following strap line on my resume

> A dynamic, creatively thinking and result-oriented IT professional with 11+ years of experience in Web Technologies, IT Administration, IT Support and Database Administration.

In Microsoft Word it always shows a green line (like  underline) indicating a grammatical error, as shown below.

[image]

I am not sure how to rephrase it to make it grammatically correct.
Help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "under it"? Do you mean under each instance of the word "IT"?

Comment: I meant like `underline`, Yes whole work is marked with green line

Comment: It may simply be because MS Word reads it as an incomplete sentence. Nothing wrong with that if it’s a heading.

Comment: Almost all word processors have very bad grammar detection. Do not rely on it to be truthful.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is a fragment.  It doesn't have a verb, thus Microsoft Word views it as grammatically wrong.  If you simply put "I am" at the beginning of the sentence, Microsoft Word would view it as accurate.

A word of caution -- do not use Microsoft Word's native grammar checker to check documents as it is frequently wrong and/or missing massive amounts of mistakes.  I would suggest using programs like the following:

- [Pro Writing Aid](http://prowritingaid.com/en/Analysis/Editor)
- [Grammarly](http://www.grammarly.com/?q=grammar&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Search&utm_content=28994270166&utm_term=grammar%20checker&matchtype=e&placement=&network=g&gclid=CLPE-O6WpbsCFUjxOgodl20A_g)

I have more experience with Pro Writing Aid, but I hear Grammarly is very good as well.  They both have a plug-in for Microsoft Word as well as an online tool.

[Pro Writing Aid Word add-in](http://prowritingaid.com/en/App/Office)

[Grammarly Word add-in](http://www.grammarly.com/office-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just say "result-oriented IT professional" and remove the "IT" everywhere else. Alternatively, use a different word instead of repeating yourself, such as "system administration" instead of "IT administration".

Also, one style note, avoid meaningless buzzwords like "result-oriented". And instead of "creatively thinking", just say "creative".